# How to find/watch the dimensions of a view in a NativeScript layout?

Tags: nativescript

When my layout loads any view inside of it has a width and height of `NaN`, it also has a `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasuredWidth()` of `0`.

At some point `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasuredWidth()` (after the layout is laid out I guess) receive useful values.

How can I get the dimensions of anything? How can I watch them change?? When will `.width` and `.height` ever not be `NaN`??? Why can't I make a view hover over the entire screen????

So far I've been **polling** every 100ms and I feel pretty dumb. Please help.

Comment: A view has the `width` and `height` property (see [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/core/view/View.html),but what's your end goal here, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EmilOberg To clarify my `width` and `height` are always `NaN` until I set them. I'm trying to watch the dimensions of an `AbsoluteLayout` so I can reorganize its children accordingly. But this is a general question of how in the world can you get the dimensions of a View in NativeScript (and watch it change).

Comment: I upvoted this question, because the two mentioned methods were the solution to the problem that every dimension-property on a page is "auto", 0 or negative numbers. I was lucky not getting NaNs.

Answer (score 16):

### Use the correct import:

```
const platform = require("platform")
```

or if you are using [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript)[angular2-nativescript](/questions/tagged/angular2-nativescript)

```
import {screen} from "platform"
//or import {screen} from "tns-core-modules/platform/platform"
```

then you can use it depending on your language like this :

### Typescript:

```
screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs //for example : 640
screen.mainScreen.widthPixels
screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs
screen.mainScreen.heightPixels
```

[mainScreen](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_platform_.screen.html#mainscreen) implements the [ScreenMetrics](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_platform_.screenmetrics.html) interface allowing access to the different screen sizes.

### JS:

```
platform.screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs //for example : 640
platform.screen.mainScreen.widthPixels
platform.screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs
platform.screen.mainScreen.heightPixels
```

NOTE: this properties are the dimensions of the mobile device screen.

Comment: Does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @Tyg While it doesn't specifically answer the question, its the first hit on Google if you search for `get screen height in nativescript` and in that context, the answer is pretty relevant.

Comment: Well at least the above import doesn't work - 

`import {screen} from "platform"
//or import {screen} from "tns-core-modules/platform/platform"`

Use this: 

`import { Screen } from '@nativescript/core';`
Screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs

Answer (score 9):

you can try `view.getActualSize().width/height` on `navigatedTo` event.
only on this event you can get the actual `height/width` of a `layout/view`

you can refer [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-get-the-height-of-a-layout-without-declaring-the-height/4082/7?u=sagar1911)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to watch for the `layoutChanged` event of `View`. It is fired every time the layout process is done incl. view resize

```
myView.on("layoutChanged", function(){
    console.log("layout change");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When NS fires loaded event for a view, it has not been rendered at this point yet. That's why all your views inside have 0 height and width. You can workaround by waiting for sometime and than try to get the view dimensions. Add this to your loaded function:

```
var height = 0

function checkIfViewRendered() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        height = view.getMeasuredHeight()
    }, 100)
    if (height === 0) checkIfViewRendered()
    else console.log('rendered height is', height)
}

checkIfViewRendered()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: EXCEPTION: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: add limit of trials to prevent this error to occur, it seems your view is not rendering at all

Comment: This recursive call is a bad idea. Use setInterval() instead - more a generic comment.

Comment: Does not answer the question at all. The question excludes polling.

Comment: put the if block in the timeout

Answer (score 2):

> How can I watch them change??

You can configure some variables when the device rotates, too:

in **Angular2**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import * as application from "application";

@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ngOnInit() {
        this.setIsScreenWide();
        application.on(application.orientationChangedEvent, this.onOrientationChanged, this);
    }

    isScreenWide: boolean;

    setIsScreenWide() {
        let widthDIPs = screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs;
        this.isScreenWide = widthDIPs >= 480;
    }

    onOrientationChanged = (args: application.OrientationChangedEventData) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setIsScreenWide();
            }, 17 /* one frame @ 60 frames/s, no flicker */);
        });
    };

    ngOnDestroy() {
        application.off(application.orientationChangedEvent, this.onOrientationChanged, this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `layoutChangedEvent` to respond to the view being resized. If your view is called `view`, something like the following should do the trick:

```
import { View } from "ui/core/view";
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';

// ...

view.on(View.layoutChangedEvent, (e:EventData) => {
  const size = view.getActualSize();
  // ... do something with the size
});
```

Comment: For me `View.layoutChangedEvent` gives `undefined`, but the `"layoutChanged"` string works.

Answer (score 1):

you can subscribe to the `navigatedTo` event of the page, that seems to occur after the view has been laid out. There the `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasuredWidth()` methods should return a value.

In the xml file add:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" navigatedTo="{{ navigated }}">
<DockLayout id="mainLayout">
...
</DockLayout>
```

In the ts file add the matching method:

```
public navigated(args:EventData){
        alert ("My view height is " + this.myView.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
```

and in the pageLoaded event link `myView`to your view:

```
public pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
    this.page = <Page>args.object;
    this.page.bindingContext = this;
    this.myView = <DockLayout>this.page.getViewById("mainLayout");        
}
```

Hope this helps.

Stefano

Comment: the `navigatedTo` event does not have a `this` reference or any attribute that I can find that let's me access my view.

Comment: @Michael You can get a reference to the view in the loaded event, then access the stored reference in the navigated event.

```js
public pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
        this.page = <Page>args.object;
        this.layout = <StackLayout>this.page.getViewById("mainLayout");
     } 
```

Comment: oh OK! I had no idea `this` persisted across these functions. Thank you! I will try it out.

Comment: sorry but this method doesn't seem to work on my NativeScript version (1.6.1).

Comment: I've just tested it in 1.6.1 with the iOS emulator and it seems to work... are you using Android? Have you got some code to show? maybe some linking is missing... we could take a look...

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
this.webView.on(WebView.loadedEvent, () => {
  this.webView.on(WebView.layoutChangedEvent, () => {
    this.size = this.webView.getActualSize();
    console.log("size: ", this.size);
  });
});
```